# How to highlight Java syntax in a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, syntaxhighlighter, google-code-prettify

I know this is an old question but answers available are either not working or depreciated for the newer versions of android. please provide a solution which will work in Android 5.0 and above.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

    String javacode="import java.util.Scanner;\n" +
            "class Addigit\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "public static void main(String args[])\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);\n" +
            "System.out.println(\"enter the no..\");\n" +
            "int n=sc.nextInt();\n" +
            "int fd=n%10;\n" +
            "int rd=n/10;\n" +
            "int sd=rd%10;\n" +
            "rd=rd/10;\n" +
            "int td=rd%10;\n" +
            "System.out.println((fd+sd+td));\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}";

    textView.setText(javacode);
}
```

how to highlight the syntax just like stackoverflow is doing with this java code or similar to what Android studio does.

Comment: Try to use the regular expression for all java keyword.So use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a magic place where you ask for some code and everyone rushes to write it for you.We are here to help you with the code you have written and provide you with some help

Comment: I also agree with cssGeek. Next time always remember when you upload question.But at that time I give the solution.

Comment: i agree with both of you, i will definitely put the code sample with question from next time, thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Use this

```
String javacode="Your Java Code";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("float"); //Java keyword
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(javacode);
SpannableString str = new SpannableString(javacode);
while (m.find()) {
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), m.start(), m.end()-1, 0);                       
}
textView.setText(str);
```

Comment: this one is working fine but i will have to write code for each java keyword..., isn't there any better solution where keywords will be automatically detected...?

Comment: Yes or you can use the split() the java code with spaces and make another string array array for all java keyword and matches the java code each word with array of java keyword.

Mark correct and upvote of my answer.